# Streaming through list of objects to retrieve object with specific Enum

Tags: java, enums

I have class Question:

```
public class Question {
private String question, correctAnswer, answer1, answer2, answer3;
private Topic topic;
private Difficulty difficulty;

public Question(String question, String correctAnswer, String answer1, String answer2, String answer3, Topic topic, Difficulty difficulty) {
    this.question = question;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.answer1 = answer1;
    this.answer2 = answer2;
    this.answer3 = answer3;
    this.topic = topic;
    this.difficulty = difficulty;
}
Getters & setters.....
```

Enum Difficulty class:

```
public enum Difficulty {
EASY,MEDIUM
```

}

When I Create an object

```
 public List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
 public void addQuestion(Question q){
    this.questions.add(q);
}

 Question q1 = new Question("What is the Queen of England?", "Elizabeth", "Patrick", "John", "Philip", Topic.HISTORY, Difficulty.EASY);
    Question q2 = new Question("When did WW2 Started??", "1939", "1945", "1942", "1938", Topic.HISTORY, Difficulty.MEDIUM);
addQuestion(q1);
addQuestion(q2);
```

Controller Class:

```
public class Controller {
public List<Question> questions;
public int currentQuestion = 0;

public void initialize(){
    List<Question> easyQuestions;
    easyQuestions = questions.stream().filter(q-> q.getQuestion().contains(q.getDifficulty())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I want to stream through questions and retrieve questions that have difficulty easy, how can I do this with streaming? As right now I get only errors :D

Comment: Stream provides `filter` method. Create Predicate which checks if question has difficulty you want and use it. Some examples: https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-filter-examples/

Comment: Thanks for that link, it was really helpful, however;
I managed to make 2 streams one that gets questions, another that gets difficulties:
List<String> question = questions.stream().map(Question::getQuestion).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Difficulty> diff = questions.stream().map(Question::getDifficulty).collect(Collectors.toList());


Yet, I fail to get the question depending on its difficulty, and I am not sure how to change my stream.

Comment: You may want to read example 2 once again. Specifically 2.2 section.